# Creating an AWK For Loop out of piped commands

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The following command does exactly what I need it to do
it checks if a string exist in a column and if not adds a comma.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Reading Comprehension/ { $5 = $5 "," } 1' somefile.csv \
| awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Sentence Skills/ { $6 = $6 "," } 1' \
| awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Arithmetic/ { $7 = $7 "," } 1' \
| awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/College Level Math/ { $8 = $8 "," } 1' \
| awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Elementary Algebra/ { $9 = $9 "," } 1' > endfile.csv
```

How do I take this concatenated/piped command and turn it into an awk loop?

I am thinking something like this:

```
awk -F, OFS=,
i = Reading Comprehension, Sentence Skills, Arithmetic, College Level Math, Elementary Algebra 
j = 5,6,7,8,9
{for ((i<=NF; j<=NF) '!/i/ { $j = $j "," } 1')}
```

Sample Input:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Elementary Algebra 34
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Sentence Skills 104,Arithmetic 08,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 115
```

Sample Output:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,,,Elementary Algebra 34
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,Arithmetic 08,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,Sentence Skills 104,,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,Sentence Skills 104,,,Elementary Algebra 115
```

I am still learning AWK and only have a partial understanding on how to do awk loops.

Any help would be appreciated, and an explanation with the Answer would truly be amazing.

Comment: better post some sample input / desired output. Regarding the code itself, piping awk 5 times seems to be too much. Note you can say `awk '/condition/ {do things} /condition2/ {do other things}' file`

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, i was thinking of doing that as well, but still leaves me with a super long command. I was trying to find the most efficient way to do it and easiest to read

Comment: efficient != visually beautiful. Piping means going through all the data over and over again. Again: post some data so we can give a further check. It looks like you are appending commas in a comma separated file, but not sure exactly how

Comment: @fedorqui i added the sample input and output and like i mentioned, the piped commands does exactly what I need. I was just trying to clean it up a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that the first word in each category is unique:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    {
        delete val                 # clear the previous values if any
        for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) {
            split($i, a, " ")
            val[a[1]] = $i         # a[1] is the first space-separated word
        }
        print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5, val["Reading"],    # null values are OK
                              val["Sentence"], 
                              val["Arithmetic"], 
                              val["College"], 
                              val["Elementary"]
    }
' input
```

Comment: @glenn jackman so a bit of a wrinkle. the place i am getting the files from that i am parsing, just change how the files are ordered...basically there is no order. any idea how to do get them in the order i mentioned in my question, even if each row is in a different order for the last 5 columns?

Comment: well I'll be d@mmed, your script doesnt care what order it is in....I wish I could kiss you.

Comment: @moore1emu, the output order is defined in the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, but since we're changing NF with each missing column, some awk array dance was required.

```
BEGIN 
{
   FS=OFS=","
   n=split("Reading Comprehension,Sentence Skills,Arithmetic,College Level Math,Elementary Algebra",c,",")
}

{
   delete a;
   for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) {
     for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
       if ($i ~ c[j]) a[j]=$i
     }
   }

   print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]
}
```

Comment: i understand the top part and some of the for part. but can you elaborate on the IF part and the print at the end? Thanks

Comment: the array `a` will hold the columns in position.  For the relevant fields i>=6, it scans the names stored in `c` and if matches puts in the correct position. Once all fields are consumed prints the first static columns and array `a` elements.  Some elements of `a` will not be initialized (those are the missing ones) but will be printed as empty string so you'll get the same number of fields for each row.