# Reorder Columns by String Variable

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

I have a csv file like so:

```
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Sentence Skills 67,Reading Comprehension 59,Elementary Algebra 41
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Sentence Skills 44,Reading Comprehension 40
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 39
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Elementary Algebra 41,Sentence Skills 82
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 82
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Sentence Skills 85
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Elementary Algebra 51
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 71,Sentence Skills 54,Elementary Algebra 33
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 70,Elementary Algebra 23,Arithmetic 42,Sentence Skills 75
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Sentence Skills 96,Reading Comprehension 88
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Elementary Algebra 53,Sentence Skills 97
```

The first 5 columns are always the same, the last 5 columns are always in a different order. I need to keep the first 5 columns the same and reorder the last 5 columns to always be in the following order Reading Comprehension,Sentence Skills,Arithmetic,College Level Math,Elementary Algebra

If one of the strings doesnt exist add a comma

So the end result would look like this:

```
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 59,Sentence Skills 67,,,Elementary Algebra 41
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 40,Sentence Skills 44,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 39,,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,,Sentence Skills 82,,,Elementary Algebra 41
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,,Sentence Skills 104,,,Elementary Algebra 82
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,,Sentence Skills 85,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,,,,,Elementary Algebra 51
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 71,Sentence Skills 54,,,Elementary Algebra 33
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 70,Sentence Skills 75,Arithmetic 42,,Elementary Algebra 23
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,Reading Comprehension 88,Sentence Skills 96,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-12-03,2015-06-23,,Sentence Skills 97,,,Elementary Algebra 53
```

If they were always in the same order i could do something like this:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Reading Comprehension/ { $5 = $5 "," } 1'
```

and if they were always at least in the same columns together i could just do a

```
awk {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8,$6,$9,$10}
```

but each row being in a different order and having a number variable at the end as thrown me for a loop.

I would like to do this with AWK, but i am open to anything at this point.

logically speaking i think i need to do something like: j = Reading*, i = Sentence*, k = Arithmetic *, l = College *, m = Elementary *

then awk {print $6j,$7i,$8k,$9l,$10m}

But my googling has return miminal results. so even if the comment is look here or look for this or check out this answer...that would be greatly appreciated

note: I did my best to make sure the input and output are correct. I have posted another question similar to this, but that was when columns were always in the same order. so this is a different request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple clean solution written in python. You have to replace `input.csv` and `output.csv` with your CSV files.

```
import csv 

labels = [
    "Reading Comprehension", "Sentence Skills", "Arithmetic",
    "College Level Math", "Elementary Algebra"
]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile, \
     open('input.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    reader = csv.reader(infile) 

    for row in reader: 
        head = row[:5]
        tail = []
        for label in labels:
            tail.append(next((i for i in row[5:] if i.startswith(label)), ""))
        writer.writerow(head + tail)
```

Here is another shorter solution, which uses piping:

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
from sys import stdin, stdout

labels = [
    "Reading Comprehension", "Sentence Skills", "Arithmetic",
    "College Level Math", "Elementary Algebra"
]

for line in stdin: 
    values = line.strip().split(',')
    stdout.write(','.join(values[:5]))
    for label in labels:
        stdout.write(',')
        stdout.write(next((i for i in values[5:] if i.startswith(label)), ''))
    stdout.write('\n')
stdout.flush()
```

If you save this code in a file, for example called `reorder`, and make this file executable, you can reformat your CSV file like this:

```
$ cat input.csv | ./reorder
```

The reformatted csv content is then written to the standard output.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you answered it yourself, but since I had already written this all up (and since it doesn't require the first word to be unique like that awk solution, just that no category is a substring of any other):

In perl, this could be solved by the following.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @categories = ('Reading Comprehension', 'Sentence Skills', 'Arithmetic', 'College Level Math', 'Elementary Algebra');

while(<ARGV>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split(/,/);
    print join(',', @columns[0 .. 4], map { my $c = $_; (grep { /$c/ } @columns)[0] || '' } @categories)."\n";
}
```

This can either accept the filename as input or standard input if no argument is provided.

The explanation of the join line is that you want the first 5 columns, followed by the first column that matches a given category or an empty string if no column matches.

`map { my $c = $_; ... } @categories`: Do this for every category (with $c representing the category instead of $_)
`grep { /$c/ } @columns`: All columns who match the given category
`(...)[0] || ''`: The first thing that matches or the empty string

As a one-liner, this can be represented as the following:

```
perl -nalF, -e 'print join(",", @F[0 .. 4], map { my $c = $_; (grep { /$c/ } @F)[0] || "" } ("Reading Comprehension", "Sentence Skills", "Arithmetic", "College Level Math", "Elementary Algebra"));' inputfile.txt
```

`-n`: implicitly put a `WHILE(<ARGV>){}` block around the code provided
`-a`: Automatically split the line and put the results in @F
`-l`: Automatically remove newlines from the input and add them to the output
`-F,`: Split on commas instead of the default of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Another perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @column_order = (
   'Reading Comprehension',
   'Sentence Skills',
   'Arithmetic',
   'College Level Math',
   'Elementary Algebra',
);

my $csv = 'foo.csv'; # CHANGME

# Open the File
open my $fh, $csv
    or die "Unable to open $csv : $!";

# Read through the file, line-by-line
while (<$fh>) {
    my @columns = split /,/; # Split each line by ','
    my $first_five = join ',', splice @columns, 0, 5; # Remove the first 5 columns
    my %data = map { $_ => '' } @column_order;  # default to empty for each column

    # iterate over remaing columns
    for my $col (@columns) {
        # if we match any of our desired columns
        if (my ($match) = grep { $col =~ m|^$_| } @column_order) {
            $col =~ s|\s*$||; # delete any trailing whitespace
            $data{$match} = $col; # store it in a hash
        }
    }
    my $remaining_columns = join ',', @data{@column_order}; # join the hash values
    print $first_five . ',', $remaining_columns . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the Code that @Glenn Jackson posted here: [Creating an AWK For Loop out of piped commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008106/creating-an-awk-for-loop-out-of-piped-commands)

and is below:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
{
    delete val                 # clear the previous values if any
    for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i, a, " ")
        val[a[1]] = $i         # a[1] is the first space-separated word
    }
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5, val["Reading"],    # null values are OK
                          val["Sentence"], 
                          val["Arithmetic"], 
                          val["College"], 
                          val["Elementary"]
}
' input
```

does exactly what i need and works perfectly and makes enough sense i can adapt it.